# Changing the limits of a power series

Tags: power-series

I don't know how to change the limits of the summations of the power series. Am I allowed to rewrite the
$$
\sum_{i=0}^pa_i\,r^{i+4}-\sum_{i=2}^pa_i\,r^{i+2}+\sum_{i=4}^pa_i\,r^i-\sum_{i=3}^pa_i\,r^{i+1}=0 \tag{1}
$$
as
$$
\sum_{i=4}^pa_{i-4}\,r^{i}-\sum_{i=4}^pa_{i-2}\,r^{i}+\sum_{i=4}^pa_i\,r^i-\sum_{i=4}^pa_{i-1}\,r^{i}=0 \tag{2}
$$
??
Note that the upper limit of summations is not $\infty$

Comment: No, your upper limit changes to when $p<\infty$.

Comment: In order, $p+4,p+2,p,p+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\sum_{i=0}^pa_ir^{i+4}=a_0r^4+\ldots+a_pr^{p+4}$$
and 
$$\sum_{i=4}^pa_{i-4}r^{i}=a_0r^4+\ldots+a_{p-4}r^{p}$$
so you want to adjust the top limit from $p$ to $p+4$ (and accordingly for the other parts).

Once you have done that, collecting like powers is easy:
$$\begin{align}0
&=\sum_{i=0}^pa_i\,r^{i+4}-\sum_{i=2}^pa_i\,r^{i+2}+\sum_{i=4}^pa_i\,r^i-\sum_{i=3}^pa_i\,r^{i+1}\\
&=\sum_{i=4}^{p+4}a_{i-4}\,r^{i}-\sum_{i=4}^{p+2}a_{i-2}\,r^{i}+\sum_{i=4}^pa_i\,r^i-\sum_{i=4}^{p+1}a_{i-1}\,r^{i}\\
&=\sum_{i=4}^p\left(a_{i-4}\,r^{i}-a_{i-2}\,r^{i}+a_i\,r^i-a_{i-1}\,r^{i}\right)\\&\qquad+(a_{p-3}r^{p+1}+a_{p-2}r^{p+2}+a_{p-1}r^{p+3}+a_pr^{p+4})\\&\qquad-(a_{p-1}r^{p+1}+a_pr^{p+2})-a_pr^{p+1}\\
&=\sum_{i=4}^p(a_{i-4}-a_{i-2}+a_i-a_{i-1})r^i\\&\qquad+(a_{p-3}-a_{p-1}-a_p)r^{p+1}+(a_{p-2}-a_p)r^{p+2}+a_{p-1}r^{p+3}+a_pr^{p+4}\end{align} $$

Comment: Thanks, Then How can I treat eq 1 to get a recursion relation? as far as I know, I need to equalize the powers and summations at first

Comment: @Wisdom A recursion relation for what?